# How to prevent iframe from accessing parent window but allow parent window to access iframe document?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Basically, I would like to have something like this (it's ES6):

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

<script>
  var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument;
  iframeDoc.open('text/html', 'replace');
  iframeDoc.write(`
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <script>
          // do not allow window.parent access!
          alert(window.parent.document.cookie);
        <\/script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
  iframeDoc.close();
</script>
```

The alert box displays the parent window's cookie, which is bad. I would like the iframe to execute its own sandboxed javascript code though. Is this even possible in HTML5?

I've tried every permutation of the `sandbox` attribute and its values.

It might be possible to construct the iframe with its contents as a data URI to the `src` attribute, but this seems kind of hacky. (Or maybe not? Aren't there restrictions on the URI length?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `sandbox`?

W3C has pretty good documentation about this and it will prevent top-level browsing context.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Also check out this tutorial:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the question that I tried using `sandbox` but it doesn't allow for the specific requirement that I have (it can block in both directions, iframe to parent or parent to iframe, but not only one direction).

Comment: Check this blog posting on how to accomplish this with JS and sandbox.  https://benfrain.com/sandbox-local-htmlcss-code-snippets-inside-iframe-style-guidespattern-libraries/

Comment: Updated answer with better blog posting.

Comment: That blog post seems to be more about sandboxing CSS than JS. It does nothing to prevent the iframe javascript from accessing the parent window.

Comment: The point of that posting as well as the HTML5Rocks one I just posted, is that you can communicate with a sandboxed iframe.  Multiple ways of doing it.  The HTML5 one is a better example of passing content using a messenger.

Comment: I would prefer if the iframe didn't have any bootstrapping code (I would like to specify the contents of the entire document at once), but it could work. Thanks for your help!